# Equivalent of logname for profile

Tags: login, .profile, dash-shell

I'm getting an error when entering my session because I'm using [`logname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/logname.1posix.html) in my `.profile`, and apparently Ubuntu doesn't like it. It says something along the lines of

```
logname: login name not found
```

I don't know whether this is because `dash` and not `bash` is executing my profile, or whether it's just a logical error from logname so early in the session. Is there any other way that I can get the login name of the user?

Comment: use `$LOGNAME`.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you :) May I ask whether this is a portable solution to other Linux distros and possibly OSX?

Comment: @Rinzwind, would you post this as an answer, so we can resolve this question? Moreover, why would `logname` not work? Is that a bug, or is there some reasons which makes sense?